# Collecting iOS Phone Book Contacts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

With introduction of iOS 6, I read apple added Contacts privacy settings as explained [here](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2012/06/ios-6-new-privacy-settings.html).

However, in prior iOS versions, this setting is not present and user privacy is at risk especially after people realized that 'Path' was dumping iOS contacts on its servers.

If an application wants to collect phone book data in iOS 5 or previous versions, which is the better way of doing it?

1. Ask for permissions explicitly once via `UIAlertView`.
2. Ask for permissions every time the back up is made via `UIAlertView`.
3. Create an application entry in `Settings` and ask user for permissions once.
4. Shun the idea of Phone Book backup altogether.

Comment: You might want to just require iOS 6 (even though this will exclude prior iOS devices) just to cover yourself / your company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think personally you may want to think about bailing on the idea as it seems to be a bit of a quagmire security wise, we are building an app at the moment that uses the address book for invitation purposes and we present a UIAlertView informing the user that we are access and not storing every time the view loads, annoying but it covers us.